# html5 canvas stretch side of a rectangle

Tags: html, canvas

is it possible that I can stretch side of a rectangle and change its shape from straight line to something else like arc or something by stretching it from center like shown below

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably wouldn't want to use an arc as suggested by someone else, as an arc will only give you, well an arc. A better approach would be to represent your rectangle (4 sides) as 4 cubic beziers. A cubic bezier with control points that are collinear with the start and end points will produce a straight line, so you can still represent a normal rectangle. Then when you want to stretch the sides into a curve, you simply move the control points out, in, up or down depending on the curve you want. It would probably be beneficial to get  a [quick understanding of beziers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve).

I'll make a picture to illustrate this better and include it in several minutes.

[image: Constructing a rectangle out of cubic beziers]

So when we draw our rectangle the code will look something like this:

```
ctx.moveTo(p1.x,p1.y);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(cp1.x,cp1.y,cp2.x,cp2.y,p2.x,p2.y);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(cp3.x,cp3.y,cp4.x,cp4.y,p3.x,p3.y);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(cp5.x,cp5.y,cp6.x,cp6.y,p4.x,p4.y);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(cp7.x,cp7.y,cp8.x,cp8.y,p1.x,p1.y);
```

Comment: After your suggestion I also found [**Quadratic Curve**](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-quadratic-curves/). Can I use this also?

Comment: Certainly, a quadratic curve is still a bezier, just quadratic. A cubic bezier will just give you another degree of freedom in creating curves. A quadratic is also a cubic bezier but with both control points at the same location. Either one will work, but I'd go with a cubic bezier for more freedom in the curve unless you know you only want to support a limited curve.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this by simply drawing a rectangle. However you can draw the three lines and draw an arc for the fourth side. [Here's a tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-arcs/) on `context.arc()`.

Comment: actually I want a rectangle which will have normal sides then I want to stretch any side of rectangle to change its shape.

Comment: @Sandy that's not possible - you can't create a non rectangle canvas

Comment: just an example of what possible - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kU5tw/) But the canvas is still rectangular ( red border )

Answer (score 0):

you can use quadraticCurveTo function it has 4 parameters and is quite easy to use look at the example at

http://jsfiddle.net/55Ws3/

```
<canvas width="800" height="800" id="world" style="border: 1px solid red;"><p class="noCanvas">You need a <a href="#">modern browser</a> to view this.</p></canvas>


var canvasElement = document.getElementById('world');
// Always check for properties and methods, to make sure your code doesn't break 
// in other browsers.
if (canvasElement && canvasElement.getContext) {
    // Get the 2d canvasContext.
    // Remember: you can only initialize one canvasContext per element.
    var canvasContext = canvasElement.getContext('2d');
    if (canvasContext) {
        canvasContext.beginPath();
        canvasContext.moveTo(100, 200);
        canvasContext.lineTo(200, 200);
        canvasContext.quadraticCurveTo(325, 250, 200, 300);
        canvasContext.lineTo(100, 300);
        canvasContext.lineTo(100, 200);
        canvasContext.fillStyle = 'red';
        canvasContext.strokeStyle = 'red';
        canvasContext.lineWidth = 2;
        canvasContext.fill();
        canvasContext.stroke();
        canvasContext.closePath();
    }
}
```